# Getting the Average of Two Arrays Elements in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, average

I am trying to get the average of the elements in two arrays such that of these:

> numbers() = (0.9716, 0.9699, 0.9686, 0.9655, 0.965, 0.9636, 0.9618, 0.9607, 0.9581, 0.9575, 0.9562, 0.9549, 0.9523)
>
> numbers2() = (0.9555, 0.9551, 0.9528, 0.951, 0.9511, 0.9488, 0.9475, 0.9467, 0.945, 0.9436, 0.9433, 0.9414, 0.9405)

> avgList() = (0.96355, 0.9625 ...)

Here is what I tried. I think I am close but I am unfamiliar with array lists.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim numbers() As Double
Dim numbers2() As Double

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
    numbers = text.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Val(s)).ToArray()

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers))
End Sub

Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim text = "+0.9555 mA,+0.9551 mA,+0.9528 mA,+0.9510 mA,+0.9511 mA,+0.9488 mA,+0.9475 mA,+0.9467 mA,+0.9450 mA,+0.9436 mA,+0.9433 mA,+0.9414 mA,+0.9405 mA"
    numbers2 = text.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Val(s)).ToArray()

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers2))
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim AList As ArrayList = New ArrayList((numbers)(numbers2))

    Dim i As Double = 0
    Dim count As Double = 0
    Dim avgList As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)()

    For Each arr As Double() In AList
        i = 0
        count += 1
        For Each thing As Double In arr
            i += 1
            If avgList.Count >= i Then
                avgList.Item(i) = ((avgList.Item(i) + thing) / count)
            Else
                avgList.Add(i)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are hoping for by posting the question, please? Are you finding errors in the calculation? Too many or too few results? Something else?

Comment: I do really not understand what you try to do: the "average" of two values: add value 1 and 2 and divide by 2 .... if this values are in an array, do that in a loop.

Comment: You could use `Dim avgs = numbers1.Zip(numbers2, Function(a, b) (a + b) / 2)`.

Comment: ArrayList should not be used in new code.

Comment: Again, I tell you to turn on Option Strict now and for all your code. See the Compile tab of the Project Properties.

Comment: Even if you did use an array list, there is no constructor that looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0) to concatenate two sequences and then use [Average](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=net-5.0) to get the average of the new sequence:

```
Dim numbers() As Double
Dim numbers2() As Double

Dim text As String
text = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
numbers = text.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Val(s)).ToArray()

text = "+0.9555 mA,+0.9551 mA,+0.9528 mA,+0.9510 mA,+0.9511 mA,+0.9488 mA,+0.9475 mA,+0.9467 mA,+0.9450 mA,+0.9436 mA,+0.9433 mA,+0.9414 mA,+0.9405 mA"
numbers2 = text.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) Val(s)).ToArray()

MsgBox(numbers.Concat(numbers2).Average)
```

This gets you the overall average of values in both arrays. You seem to want the average of each array position in both arrays:

```
Dim averages As New List(Of Double)
Dim items As Integer

' Get common number of items
If numbers.Length > numbers2.Length Then
    items = numbers2.Length
Else
    items = numbers.Length
End If

For counter = 0 To items - 1
    averages.Add((numbers(counter) + numbers2(counter)) / 2)
Next
```

`averages` now contains the average of each array position.

Comment: `For counter = 0 To Math.Min(numbers.Length, numbers2.Length) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, I'm responding on the basis that your want to end up with an array of two values that are the average of the numeric values contained in your two strings. Correct?

If so, then

```
Dim sNums1 As String = "+0.9716 mA,+0.9699 mA,+0.9686 mA,+0.9655 mA,+0.9650 mA,+0.9636 mA,+0.9618 mA,+0.9607 mA,+0.9581 mA,+0.9575 mA,+0.9562 mA,+0.9549 mA,+0.9523 mA"
Dim sNums2 As String = "+0.9555 mA,+0.9551 mA,+0.9528 mA,+0.9510 mA,+0.9511 mA,+0.9488 mA,+0.9475 mA,+0.9467 mA,+0.9450 mA,+0.9436 mA,+0.9433 mA,+0.9414 mA,+0.9405 mA"
Dim dAvgs As Double() = {sNums1 .Split(","c).Select(Function(x) Val(x)).Average(), sNums2 .Split(","c).Select(Function(x) Val(x)).Average()}
```

Result:

```
{0.96197692307692306, 0.9478692307692308}
```

**EDIT**

I just realised from your example result that you're looking for an average between *each of the numeric values* in each string. Therefore:

```
Dim dNums1 As IEnumerable(Of Double) = sNums1.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) Val(x))
Dim dNums2 As IEnumerable(Of Double) = sNums2.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) Val(x))
Dim dAvgs As Double() = dNums1.Zip(dNums2, Function(n1, n2) (n1 + n2) / 2).ToArray()
```

Result:

```
{0.96355, 0.96249999999999991, 0.9607, 0.95825, ...}
```

I'll leave the previous code there in case anyone needs it.

Comment: Sure @AndrewMorton. `System.Link.Zip` function acts as a conduit between two collections of values to sequentially perform a user-defined function on them. In this case, a simple averaging of two decimal numbers. Conceptually, it does act a bit like a zipper, joining the two sets of "teeth" (values).

Answer (score 0):

Button1 and Button2 remain as written in your question.

In Button3.Click I create a `List(Of T)` just as you did. Next I checked if numbers and numbers2 are the same length. We don't want any "index out of range" exceptions. The I looped through the indexes of the arrays and calculated the averages.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim avgList As New List(Of Double)
    If numbers.Length = numbers2.Length Then
        For index = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
            avgList.Add((numbers(index) + numbers2(index)) / 2)
        Next
        'Displays in Immediate window
        For Each d In avgList
            Debug.Print(d.ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```